# Can i deploy KMDF or UMDF driver on same "host" machine rather than setting up a another test environment?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-7-x64, device-driver, wdk

am stuck up with one question in mind , is there any way i can test my drivers on same machine rather than setting up and new test environment.

The reason am asking this question on this forum is that am unable to find my answer on MSDN.

I really needs to know that whether it is possible or not to test drivers on same "host" machine .

My Development Environment 
OS :  Windows 7 x64 
Kit : Windows Driver Kit 8.0 
Editor : Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate

......

Comment: I suppose you *can*, but it isn't really a very good idea.  Drivers under development tend to cause a lot of system crashes.  It's also a lot harder to identify and correct bugs without access to a debugger.

Answer (score 1):

No It Cant be , you cannot test drivers on same "host" machine ..
**Please see the image below**.. I don't yet know about UMDF drivers , will post it also as soon as possible. I cant post the image as i dont have "*at least 10 reputation to post image*" .. But i confirm KMDF drivers cant be deployed on same "host" machine.

Answer (score 0):

Well it depends on what you mean with testing, if you want to debug (via WinDbg) the answer is No, you need a VM/Test Machine etc.

Else, if you mean simply running your driver, yes you can, but it's absolutely not a good practice, due to the BSOD risk that you are going to face.

Comment: if i can , can you share a link on how to deploy windows driver on same machine ?? As am unable to find on web

Comment: Simply use the inf file that you find on your project to install it, then you can let it run by starting the service (I use processhacker to start driver services for example)